# Can somebody give me a quick rundown on what the "#f()" syntax in Emacs-Lisp is doing?

Tags: syntax, emacs, elisp, bytecode

Today, as I was once again traipsing through the Emacs Manual, I got a little tired and decided to pop into the Org Mode manual for something a little lighter, and I was reading about link handling, and ended up reading (and rereading) the *Help* documentation for `'org-file-apps`.

Well, when I peeked at the related variable `'org-file-apps-windowsnt`, I was surprised to see some syntax in its value that I didn't recognise.

To be clear, I've read the elisp manual virtually cover-to-cover, so while it's not uncommon for me to not feel comfortable with a particular bit of syntax, it's fairly rare these days that I don't recognise it at all.

The syntax in question is in the following expression

```
((remote . emacs)
 (system . #f(compiled-function
          (file path)
          #<bytecode -0x47e8150df949387>))
 (t . #f(compiled-function
     (file path)
     #<bytecode -0x47e8150df949387>)))
```

Specifically, the `#f()` syntax.

I tried searching across my Info manuals in Emacs, but only came up with entries related to colour values (e.g., #FFFFFF for white), next I tried DDG and Google, but since all generalised search engines have decided that even something quoted is subject to fuzziness, I haven't turned up anything there.

So, yeah, I'm just hoping somebody can explain the `#f()` syntax in this bit of Emacs-Lisp code, and what it's doing, and maybe why it's used. I assume it must have something to do with the use of compiled bytecode, but beyond that I'm stumped.

Apologies for what is no doubt a basic question that I've simply forgotten from reading the elisp manual, but searching, including that manual, is getting me nowhere.

Comment: I've just submitted Emacs bug #[55853](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=55853) for this, asking that the `f#(...)` be documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted Emacs bug #[55853](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=55853) for this, asking that the `f#(...)` syntax be documented.

The bug was closed as "fixed" with this explanation. Apparently this is not Lisp-readable syntax but is instead intended to be for human consumption as "pretty-printed" output. I leave it to you whether you think it serves that purpose well. This is the bug-closure explanation:

> It's from:
>
> ```
> (cl-defmethod cl-print-object ((object compiled-function) stream)
>   (unless stream (setq stream standard-output))
>   ;; We use "#f(...)" rather than "#<...>" so that pp.el gives better results.
>   (princ "#f(compiled-function " stream)
> ```
>
> I.e., it's from the "pretty" version of `prin1`, and is not meant to be
> readable by the Lisp reader.
>
> [Emacs maintainer Lars has] now mentioned this in the [Special Read Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Read-Syntax.html) node in the lispref [he means the Elisp]
> manual in Emacs 28.2.

In other words, this is apparently "special read syntax", i.e., Lisp reader syntax that's *not* readable by the Lisp reader but is meant to communicate something to humans.

That description "explains the syntax" - the idea behind it. But it doesn't really tell you what the syntax is supposed to communicate to users, i.e., how to read it as a human.

I'd guess it's trying to be a placeholder, in this case, for a (compiled) function that takes arguments `FILE` and `PATH`.

What the source code for the function is; what the function does (e.g., it's doc); or where it's defined -- nothing like that is conveyed in the "pretty"-print. And whether "compiled" there means byte-compiled or "native"-compiled also isn't made clear.

Hopefully someone else may be able to add more light with another answer here. And perhaps the 18.2 doc will make things more clear.

Comment: Cheers Drew, I really appreciate your help on this one. I think my understanding is as good as it's going to get for now.

Here's hoping that the Docs shed more light on this over time. Funnily enough I've encountered it a further 2 times since posting this question, I guess at a certain code-depth you start to run into it.

It really is a dead end to understanding though, which seems to me to go against the spirit of a self-documenting editor. Hopefully it's a temporary transition period as native-comp and byte-compiling come out of their infancy, and not a permanent state of affairs.